# CodeHow to call ng-blur before ng-click for Mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my application, we have text box and button in same page. we will fetch details through ng-blur of that text box, and then we will validate those values which is retrieved from ng-blur in Button ng-click function.

But ng-click is triggering before ng-blur when customer directly click that button after entered values in text box.

Its working fine in desktop browsers that ng-blur calling before ng-click. But not working for mobile browsers. I googled solution for this, but i did not get the solution. Sorry for my english, please let us know if anybody have the solution.

Html Code :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="txndata.txnNo" id="txnNo" 
       ngomitsplchar class="form-control"
       on-blur="getTxnData(txndata)" 
       tabindex="5" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="nope">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" tabindex="17" 
        id = "validate" class="btn but_small1"
        ng-click="validate(txndata);">Enquiry</button>
```

JS Code :

```
$scope.getTxnData = function (formObj) {
    // Ajax call and other process
}

$scope.validate = function (formObj) {
    // Validation and submit process
}
```

Comment: Do you have code you can post??

Comment: @SDH Please find above my code snippet

Comment: You could consider a short timer to delay the firing of the event you want delayed. Quick hack that could potentially fix your issue.

Comment: So why are you fetching values through ng-blur? I'm confused about what you are trying to do here??? Are you trying to do basic data validation on the value being inputted into a field or what are you trying to accomplish here??

Comment: @SDH For my case, there are 4 text box and each text box have onBlur call to validate that text and get other values(through Ajax call) by that text. When customer type, say Postal code in one of the text and application will fetch district and state details. customer without tab out he directly click button in mobile browsers so ng-click trigger first and ngblur trigger secong. We have some logic writtn in ng-click. so for my case its not working. My objective is ng-blur should call first then ng-click should trigger. Its working fine in desktop versions.

Comment: Why not use ngKeyup or ngMouseleave for what you are trying to do? ngBlur is going to fire when the object is out of focus. If you type a value into a field, and then click on a button with ngClick, both events will fire at the same time, and it's a random guess about which one is going to fire first. I would either use one of those two other options or consider adding a timer delay to your event that you want to fire last.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it using the javascript rather than finding a solution on angular events.
Change your validate function in this manner.

```
this.validate= function($event) {
    // do something else
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
};
```

The `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` will not allow `ng-click` to fire directly.

One other way to solve is to make use of directive.

```
.directive('stopPropagation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Detailed description can be seen [here](https://benohead.com/blog/2015/06/09/angularjs-stopping-event-propagation-on-ng-click/)

Comment: Its not working, when i click that button, it not calling  that directive.